# Append Jquery Ajax result to existing table

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

I need to place ajax request result to existing table, how can it be done? here is my ajax request

```
$("input#order").click(function(){
    var idmenu  = $("#idmenu").val();
    var menu    = $("#idmenu :selected").text();
    var qty     = $("#qty").val();

    $.ajax({
        type    :'POST',
        url     :'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/process',
        data    :'idmenu='+idmenu+'&menu='+menu+'&qty='+qty,
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#result").html('<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/loading.gif"/>');
        },
        success:function(result){
            //result is json format
        }
    });

});
```

here is the json format from ajax request

```
{"itemname":"product1","qty":"3","prices":"4500"}
```

and here is my table format

```
<table class="list-order">
    <tr>
        <th class="order">order</th>
        <th class="qty">qty</th>
        <th class="pice">price</th>
    </tr>
    //how to append ajax result here
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit"  size="25" id="process" value="Proses"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i want to append the result from ajax like

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

and Not inside the  tag, like

```
<tr>
   <td>result is not here</td>
</tr>
```

final result look like this one

```
<table class="list-order">
    <tr>
        <th class="order">order</th>
        <th class="qty">qty</th>
        <th class="pice">price</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- result look like this -->
    <tr>
        <td>product1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        </td>4500</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end result-->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit"  size="25" id="process" value="Proses"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing the exact format of your JSON, it's hard to give a definitive answer. However, assuming you have a JSON array of objects that represent your rows, you'd need to iterate over that array and for each object do the following:

- Create a new `<tr>` element - `var $tr = $('<tr/>');`
- For each item of information (I assume one item per `<td>`), create a `<td>` element and set its content - `var $td = $('<td/>').html(x.y)` (`x` is your current object, `y` is a field in the object) then append it to the row - `$tr.append($td);`.
- Append the row before the last row in the existing table - `$('.list-order tr:last').before($tr);`

Following from the additional information provided in the question, the following code should do what you need to do:

```
success: function(result) {
    //result is json format
    var $tr = $('<tr/>');
    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.itemname));
    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.qty));
    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.prices));
    $('.list-order tr:last').before($tr);
}
```

Comment: @wenkhairu Can you also provide exactly what you'd want the resulting HTML to look like? A single `<td>` or one `<td>` per piece of information?

Comment: @wenkhairu I've edited my answer to include some specific code that should give you what you want.

Comment: $('.list-order tr:last').before($tr); may be changed to  $('#list-order tr:last').before($tr);

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma No it can't, the HTML uses a class, not an id; the two aren't interchangeable. You could (probably) change the HTML to use an id and then change the selector, though.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax success function:

```
success:function(result){
            //create new tr
            var $tr = $('<tr>');
            //extract value from result and put in tr
            $tr.html(result.someVal);
            //find first <tr> and append new tr after it
            $('table.list-order tr:first').after($tr);
         }
```